PCB Edge connector: nipples on each finger?
I am designing a footprint for a PCB edge connector. The datasheet shows in DETAIL 'A', some "nipples" at the end of each finger. I don't understand note 5 and I don't understand what these "nipples" are for.

From another source, I can see that edge connectors usually have these outgrowth tracks at the edges.  What are they? Should I add them to my footprint?

For reference here is my current footprint for the mating MECF-20-01-L-DV-WT-K-TR connector.


nowox - Hi, It seems the first two images were copied from elsewhere. To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of each copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to that material. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL). If the original source is a printed book or other offline material, then [edit] the question & add a normal citation (see the linked rule for details). TY

@SamGibson Should I add on the first image that is a datasheet from Samtec? The reference is on the image.  For the second image, I have no idea where I took it from. Perhaps some manufacturer's website. I guess I would have to delete this question since I am violating the rules :(

@nowox Just link to the datasheet in question for the first one, and for the second one, swap it for one you do know the source of.

nowox - As @Hearth has kindly just explained (quicker than I typed :) ) yes, we need the proper reference for the datasheet. Below that image, add something like "Image from Samtec datasheet for connector X" (whatever that part number is) - that's the name part of the reference - and add its link. || Hearth has suggested a good solution for the second image. Alternatively, I think I might have found the source for you to add - was it this? If so, add that link & credit "Eurocircuits - Gold Plating for Edge Connectors"

Those traces are used to short all the terminals together before the card is cut out of the panel. While immersion gold doesn't require it, hard gold that's capable of surviving dozens to hundreds of insertion cycles needs to be electroplated, and that means all the plated portions need to be electrically connected to become one of the electrodes in the plating process.

Is it something done by the manufacturer or should I add them before ordering (Eurocircuits) ?

@nowox Most fabs will do it for you, but if you want control of the process, you can do it yourself too.

The connections are required to short together the fingers so they can be electroplated with thick hard gold (typically after a nickel barrier layer). The shorted fingers become the cathode in the electroplating process. The shorting is removed later in the processing of the bare PCB when excess material is removed and the bevel is machined.
Point 5 suggests making them the width of the finger, the diagram shows something else, but it is X'd out (i.e. don't do this). Not X'ing out the detail view might be a bit confusing, but we are supposed to assume inheritance. They want you to extend the full width of the finger off the final board outline.
If you leave it to the PCB fab you lose control over what happens. Here is what PCBWay considers ideal from their pov.

